# Cannot upload or download in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, 22.04

I have problems uploading or downloading content on Ubuntu 22.04. Specifically, I have problems in the following cases:

- I cannot attach files to email on Thunderbird, Hotmail or Gmail. The screen just greys out and I have to restart my system.
- I cannot download pictures from Facebook.
- I cannot upload to Google. I cannot do a Google reverse image lookup for example.
- I cannot apply for jobs, as uploading just makes the screen go grey.

Am I missing a system setting or app in Ubuntu?

Comment: is this an issue in firefox, google chrome, or both? did it work before and stop working, or has it not worked from the start?

Comment: Any browsers (firefox, brave, chrome) crash on my system when trying to upload file. I think there's an issue on the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

As Thunderbird in 22.04 LTS will be a new instance, it will be necessary to ensure that critical settings in it are enabled.

The initial step is to ensure that in *Mail Content* under *Preferences* the *Allow remote content in messages* option is ticked.

In Thunderbird, this option is accessed by clicking on the 3 parallel lines, the so called hamburger menu option on the Thunderbird's front screen (<kbd>☰</kbd>), and selecting *Preferences*, which will open a new tab from which the selection can be made.

Then close the *Preferences* tab (the setting will be automatically remembered) and try again.

[image: Thunderbird's Preferences]

UPDATE Nov 2022 Thunderbird v102.5.0

The settings mentioned above can now be found under `Settings > Privacy and Security > Mail Content` rather than `Preferences` as in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

You should try an upgrade of the system:

1. Open a terminal (you can use the shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Type your password and wait for the repositories to update, then run:

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
3. Type `y` to confirm.
4. Moreover you probably have Firefox as a snap package so run:

   ```
   sudo snap refresh
   ```

In many cases this simple thing could resolve such problems.